# Why we need to add all fields to GROUP BY Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table `test1` and a view `view1`, and i'm wondering why I get this results:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    A_ VARCHAR(10),
    B_ VARCHAR(10),
    C_ VARCHAR(10),
    D_ VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN D_ in ('false') THEN LEFT(A_, CHARINDEX('(', A_) -1)
        ELSE D_
    END AS D,
    MIN(B_) B,
    CASE
        WHEN C_ IS NOT NULL THEN '0'
        ELSE C_
    END AS C
FROM test1
GROUP BY
    D_,
    B_,
    C_;
```

> Column 'test1.A_' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I know I have to add `A_` in the `GROUP BY` section, but why since it won't be showed in the View?
Also, why do I have the same error if I remove the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Do `GROUP BY A, C, D`.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: No, don't do `GROUPE BY A, C, D` because they are aliases so it will output an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `_A` is used in the `LEFT(A_, CHARINDEX('(', A_) -1)` you have to include it in the `GROUP BY`. It does not matter that it is in the `CASE`. The only situation that we do not have to add the attribute to `GROUP BY` is when the attribute is part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Just finding this weird that we have to add it. I know it's being used, but it's not like it's a useful information this the output of `SELECT * FROM view;` won't show `A_` at all.

Comment: @begreen You have to realize that there can be many rows with many different `A_` values for one combination of `D_, B_, C_`. The question is: which value should be used in such case?

Comment: Ok, maybe I was blind by my real code where there can be only one `A_`. But then why do I get the same error If I remove `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @BeGreen Once you have an aggregation function behind `SELECT`, there can be only attributes which are also behind `GROUP BY` outside of the aggregate function.

Comment: Ok thank you, clear answer.